# php session data not being stored on member pages after logging

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I am building a member system and i have hit a road block with php sessions, I am able to create an account but when i reach the login area and submit my details my sessions are not being stored. I have a file that require_once on every page with my session info and such. Please see below code.

I am just noe able to reach the member page because the session data is not carried over.

you can test at my site here:

http://dailypaychecknetwork.com/account/login.php

**username:** gazaian1 
**Password:** icd199444

Please help me out i have been at this for 3 days.  :(

**Page included on every page:**

```
//Require DB connection
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/connect_hostgator.php";

//Pages to require
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/languages/en.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/class.newuser.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/class.user.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/funcs.php";

session_start();

//Global User Object Var
//loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed
if(isset($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]))
{
    $loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
}
```

**Login script:**

```
require_once("models/member-config.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Prevent the user visiting the logged in page if he/she is already logged in
if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: account.php"); die(); }

//Forms posted
if(isset($_POST['dpnlogin']))
{
    $errors = array();
    $username = sanitize(trim($_POST["username"]));
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

    //Perform some validation
    //Feel free to edit / change as required
    if($username == "")
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_SPECIFY_USERNAME");
    }
    if($password == "")
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_SPECIFY_PASSWORD");
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {
        //A security note here, never tell the user which credential was incorrect
        if(!usernameExists($username))
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_OR_PASS_INVALID");
        }
        else
        {
            $userdetails = fetchUserDetails($username);
                //Hash the password and use the salt from the database to compare the password.
                $password = MD5($password);

                if($password != $userdetails["user_pass"])
                {
                    //Again, we know the password is at fault here, but lets not give away the combination incase of someone bruteforcing
                    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_OR_PASS_INVALID");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Passwords match! we're good to go'

                    //Construct a new logged in user object
                    //Transfer some db data to the session object
                    $loggedInUser = new loggedInUser();
                    $loggedInUser->user_id = $userdetails["id"];
                    $loggedInUser->username = $userdetails["userid"];
                    //$loggedInUser->user_no = $userdetails["userno"];
                    $loggedInUser->email = $userdetails["email_address"];
                    $loggedInUser->pass = $userdetails["user_pass"];
                    $loggedInUser->fname = $userdetails["f_name"];
                    $loggedInUser->lname = $userdetails["l_name"];
                    $loggedInUser->phonee = $userdetails["phone"];
                    $loggedInUser->znzsingle = $userdetails["znz_single"];
                    $loggedInUser->znzdouble = $userdetails["znz_double"];
                    $loggedInUser->empowerid = $userdetails["empower_id"];
                    $loggedInUser->znzadteamlink = $userdetails["znzadteam_link"];

                    //$loggedInUser->updateLastSignIn();
                    $_SESSION["userCakeUser"] = $loggedInUser;

                    //var_dump($_SESSION); die;

                    //Redirect to user account page
                    header("Location: account.php");
                    die();
                }
        }
    }
}

require_once("../includes/header.php");
echo "
<div class='main-content-wrap'>
    <div class='main-content'>
        <h2>Login To Your Account:</h2>

        <div id='main'>";

        echo resultBlock($errors,$successes);

        echo "  
        <div id='regbox'>
                <form name='loginUser' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
                    <table cellpadding='3px' class='mtext'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Username</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='text' name='username' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdSubHeader'><label>Password</label></td>
                                <td class='tdContent'><input type='password' name='password' size='25'/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        <br>
                        <div style='float:left;'><input type='submit' name='dpnlogin' value='Login'></div>                  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='sidebar'>
        <p>*CREATE YOUR FREE MARKETING SYSTEM TODAY*</p>
        <div class='important'>
            <b>IMPORTANT:</b>
            <p>IF YOU HAVE NOT YET SIGNED UP FOR EMPOWER NETWORK OR ZNZADTEAM.COM THEN PLEASE LEAVE THOSE FIELDS BLANK UNTIL YOU DO.</p>
        </div>
        <img class='green-button' src='../../images/leftbutton.jpg'>
    </div>
</div>
";
require_once("../includes/footer.php");
```

**Member page script:**

```
require_once("models/member-config.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Prevent the user visiting the page if he is not logged in
if(!isUserLoggedIn()){ header("Location: login.php"); die(); }

require_once("../includes/header.php");
?>
<div class='main-content-wrap'>
    <div class="back-office-head">
        <div class="date"><p>TODAY IS:</p> <p><?php echo date("F jS \, Y"); ?></p></div>
        <div class="back-office"><h1>BACK OFFICE</h1></div>
        <div class="user-meta"><p>WELCOME <?php echo $loggedInUser->username; ?>,</p> <p>TO YOUR BACK OFFICE.</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="back-office-links">
        <div class="links">
            <p>MY REFERRAL LINK:</p>
            <p><a href="#">http://www.dailypaychecknetwork.com/<?php echo $loggedInUser->username; ?></a></p>
            <br>
            <p>MY ZNZADTEAM.COM LINK:</p>
            <p><a href="#">CLICK HERE TO LEARN MORE</a></p>
            <br>
            <p>MY EMPOWER NETWORK LINK:</p>
            <p><a href="#">CLICK HERE TO LEARN MORE</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="back-office-logo">
            <a href="http://www.dailypaychecknetwork.com"><img src="../images/dpnlogo.jpg" alt="daily paycheck network" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="back-office-buttons">
        <div class="back-office-row-1">
            <div class="gsg"><a href="#"><img src="../images/gettingstartedbutton.jpg" alt="getting started guide"/></a></div>
            <div class="ui"><a href="http://www.dailypaychecknetwork.com/account/updateuser.php"><img src="../images/updateinfobutton.jpg" alt="update info"/></a></div>
            <div class="vl"><a href="#"><img src="../images/viewleadsbutton.jpg" alt="update info"/></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="back-office-row-2">
            <div class="gsg"><a href="#"><img src="../images/trainingbutton.jpg" alt="traning"/></a></div>
            <div class="ui"><a href="#"><img src="../images/autoresponderbutton.jpg" alt="autoresponder"/></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="back-office-row-3">
            <div class="gsg"><a href="#"><img src="../images/toolsbutton.jpg" alt="tools"/></a></div>
            <div class="ui"><a href="http://dailypaychecknetwork.com/account/photo.php"><img src="../images/uploadphotobutton.jpg" alt="upload photo"/></a></div>
            <div class="vt"><a href="#"><img src="../images/viewtrafficbutton.jpg" alt="view traffic stats"/></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="back-office-row-4">
            <div class="fb"><a href="#"><img src="../images/facebook.png" alt="daily paycheck network facebook"/></a></div>
            <div class="ao"><a href="#"><img src="../images/additionaloppsbutton.jpg" alt="additional opportunities"/></a></div>
            <div class="faq"><a href="#"><img src="../images/additionaloppsbutton.jpg" alt="fqa"/></a></div>
            <div class="cu"><a href="#"><img src="../images/additionaloppsbutton.jpg" alt="contact us"/></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="back-office-footer-ad-space"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/footer.php");
```

**var dump:**

```
array(1) { ["userCakeUser"]=> object(loggedInUser)#2 (12) { ["user_id"]=> int(31) ["user_no"]=> NULL ["email"]=> string(19) "nadogrand@gmail.com" ["pass"]=> string(32) "4f7253f18db6d091cd2f028bb0ab417c" ["fname"]=> string(8) "leonardo" ["lname"]=> string(9) "grandison" ["phonee"]=> string(10) "8764249826" ["username"]=> string(8) "gazaian1" ["znzsingle"]=> string(7) "1313434" ["znzdouble"]=> string(7) "1314445" ["empowerid"]=> string(9) "leodragon" ["znzadteamlink"]=> string(22) "znzadteam.com/gazaian1" } }
```

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be inside **all** files using sessions.

Comment: Also don't forget `session_cache_limiter`, pick the value public, private_no_expire or private, otherwise the standard session will be send headers 1981year (nocache)

Comment: @Fred-ii - `Page included on every page` there are the `session_start ()` included... but maybe is to set above from `//Pages to require`...

Comment: @aldanux I overlooked that, thanks. I stand corrected. I'm questioning `is_object()` though.

Comment: @OP: What is `is_object()`? That's a function. Where does this come into the picture and which framework are you using, CAKEPHP? You're also outputting before header()

Comment: This is a wall of code where too many things can go wrong. I suggest you work this on a smaller scale and workd you way up from there. There's no way I'm able or going to test this.

Comment: is_object is used to my data i updated above a var_dump of $_SESSION

Comment: i added session_start() above //pages to require but no change

Comment: This script worked fine three days ago on fatcow unitl i switched to hostgator i contacted them but they say it's nothing on there end.

Comment: I do not recommend storing objects in $_SESSION as the class definition  needs to be available when the session starts. Instead, store the id of the record and reload it from the database after starting the session.

Answer (score 1):

session_start() need to be the first call.

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.session-start.php

Comment: session_start() in this file "connect_hostgator.php"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my htaccess file i requesting two different urls one with www and one without the www. Once i requested only the url with www my sessions where fixed. Thanks for the help anyways guys.